# Trying to load library work fine on debug mode but shows java.lang.NullPointerException: on release mode

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

Running the Library work fine on debug mode but when I run the code on release, the library throws null pointer.

Any Idea on what need to be done on the library to make it work on release mode.

Any idea will be appreciated.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15357): Process: com.example.untitled2, PID: 15357
E/AndroidRuntime(15357): java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method 
kotlin.jvm.internal.k.d, parameter cardOptions
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at a.e.J1(Unknown Source:374)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at a.b.L1(Unknown Source:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        PaymentActivity.o(Unknown Source:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at m.s0.d(Unknown Source:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at m.p0.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime(15357):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: Looks like you might be using R8/Proguard on release mode, please post the complete `unobfuscated` stacktrace & the relevant code.

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

here is the build type